# Retrieve displayName and email from person or group list field in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I'm querying a `SPList` and I'm retrieving a `Person or Group` field object.

I want to get the `DisplayName` and `Email` properties but I don't know how to get them. Getters "`get_email()`" and "`get_displayName()`" throw error in console: `"Unsupported object property or method"`

I just have the `Person or Group` object by storing it in a variable directly from a `SPList`:

`var person = found.get_item( "Assigned`" );

How to get `person.get_displayName()` ?

Comment: check this, you cant directly get the user details, you will have to get using the userid
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/176319/get-person-or-group-field-from-list-then-query-user-profile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use **fieldValue.get_lookupValue()** to get the user's display name. To get more information of the user we can use the web.ensureUser() method.

The code below for your reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getItemFromList, "sp.js");
function getItemFromList(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var item = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("MyTasks").getItemById(1);
    clientContext.load(item);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){ 
            // successfully retrieved value from list item
            var assigned = item.get_item("AssignedTo");
            if(assigned.length>0){
                var user = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(assigned[0].get_lookupValue());
                clientContext.load(user);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                    function(){ 
                        // successfully ensured user from user name
                        var email = user.get_email();
                        var login = user.get_loginName();
                        var displayName = user.get_title();
                        alert("User LoginName: " + login + "\nUser Email: " + email + "\nUser Display Name: " + displayName);
                    },function(sender,args){ // on error
                        alert(args.get_message());
                    }
                );
            }          
        },
        function(sender,args){ // on error
            alert(args.get_message());
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

[image]

In SharePoint 2013, I suggest you use REST API with jQuery Ajax to achieve it. Check the article below:

[SharePoint 2013: Get User Details from Person or Group field using REST API](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31210.sharepoint-2013-get-user-details-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api.aspx)

Comment: I will mark you as the correct answer because I found the same thing in another place but it's not working on my work's SP... Maybe there's something wrong with the configuration of the site, dunno...

Comment: My work around was to use Object.keys( user ) and retrieve the value of email and displayName with keys: `var email = user[Object.keys[1]];`. I must issue a ticket because I need to work with the provided solution, not this workaround.. jaja